# Recursion: Smallest Number Of Steps

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have to write a recursive program to solve this problem:

You are given two empty buckets of 'a' liters and 'b' liters and are near a sea.
What is the smallest number of steps you need to make to isolate 'c' liters of water in one of the buckets?

Given ‘a’, ‘b’, and ‘c’ return the smallest number of steps.

I've tried to do it in a simple way, I can't apply a recursion here.

```
function steps(a,b,c){
let s = 0;
let aLimit = 0;
let bLimit = 0;

if (a + b < c){
    for (let l = 0; l < (a + b); l++){
        s += 1;
        aLimit += 1;
        if(aLimit == a){
            s+=1;
        }
        console.log(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I can't apply a recursion here` - why not? have you figured out the "algorithm" to solve the problem

Comment: do you have some numbers for the bucket sizes?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-water-jug-puzzle/. Is this the problem you are trying. If no, can you provide any examples???

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is correct but maybe it's a start. (Note that this may recurse forever if `gcd(a, b)` does not divide `c`, and may return unexpected results if `c` equals `a` or `b`.) I think there may be more efficient, [math-based](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5800/generalization-of-the-two-bucket-puzzle) answers.

```js
function f(a, b, c, steps=0, aState=0, bState=0, memo={}){
  const key = [aState, bState]
  // Solution found
  if (key.includes(c))
    return memo[key] = steps
  // Already visited 
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(key))
    return memo[key]
  // Mark as visited
  memo[key] = steps
    
  const aFree = a - aState
  const bFree = b - bState

  return steps + Math.min(
    // pour a to b
    aState ? f(a, b, c, steps + 1, Math.max(0, aState - bFree), Math.min(aState + bState, b), memo) : Infinity,
    // pour b to a
    bState ? f(a, b, c, steps + 1, Math.min(aState + bState, a), Math.max(0, bState - aFree), memo) : Infinity,
    // fill and pour a to b
    f(a, b, c, steps + 1, Math.max(0, a - bFree), Math.min(a + bState, b), memo),
    // fill and pour b to a
    f(a, b, c, steps + 1, Math.min(aState + b, a), Math.max(0, b - aFree), memo)
  )
}

console.log(f(3, 5, 4))
```